# Error [CCSprite visit]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2

hi i am in game i have multiple item in my game i have problem that when i selected the same item again and again it crash but if i select the different items it remain good and no crash happen i enable the NSZombieEnabled and got this error and didn't understand what is that mean by i retain my each sprite but error is same this is error i got

```
-[CCSprite visit]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5594c00
```

can any one help me in this case.i tried too much but didn't understand i am new on iphone game development so help me .

Answer (score 0):

That meen your `CCSprite*` pointer is pointing to deallocated object. That's how you can get this:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSomething:foo]; //reference counter is 1
[sprite release]; //reference counter is 0. object is deallocated. But sprite is still pointing to the object
[sprite visit]; // here you are trying to visit the deallocated sprite
```